# Send notification to User related to the Object collection

Tags: laravel

I have a model called `Quote` which has a `$this->belongsTo(User::class)` relation.

What I am trying todo is to query certain Quotes (Where status = 3) and then send the notification to the users of those quotes.

Example.

```
$quotes = Quote::where('status', 3)->get();

Notification::send($quotes, new RequestClientReviewNotify($quotes));
```

But the above won't work as it will try find a `email` field on `quotes` table.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `email` to the appends array in the Quote model:
`protected $appends = ['email']`

Then add this function to the Quote model:

```
public function getEmailAttribute()
{
    return $this->user->email;
}
```

Now the quotes collection should contain the users email.
I didn't test it but I should work.

Or you can join the user table:

```
Quote::select('quotetablename.*', 'users.email')
    ->where('quotetablename.status', 3)
    ->join('users', 'quotetablename.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Interesting solution - I wonder if it would always eager load the user relation when accessing only Quote collection.

Comment: @Andrew Everything in the appends array will be loaded

Comment: That might not be the best as sometimes I would only want to query the Quotes and not have a extra query for users relation.

Comment: @Andrew I understand that, you could also do a join on the users table. And select the email.

Comment: Thanks I used that second option and it works great.